# How to scope block of code?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

If I need to reference a namespace explicitly to avoid conflicts with another namespace, how can that be done when you need to reference it several times within one block of code?

For example:

```
List<NamespaceA.SomeEnum> myobject = new List<NamespaceA.SomeEnum>()
{
  NamespaceA.SomeEnum.A,
  NamespaceA.SomeEnum.B,
  NamespaceA.SomeEnum.C,
  NamespaceA.SomeEnum.D,
  NamespaceA.SomeEnum.E,
}
```

Is there a way to shortcut/imply `NamespaceA.SomeEnum` in the parameter references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
using ASomeEnum = NamespaceA.SomeEnum;
```

and then

```
List<ASomeEnum> myobject = new List<ASomeEnum>()
{
    ASomeEnum.A,
    ASomeEnum.B,
    ASomeEnum.C,
    ASomeEnum.D,
    ASomeEnum.E,
}
```

The `using` directive needs to be at the top level or within a namespace, but not within a type.

---

Another option is to move the method containing the offending code block to another file and to make the class partial.

This allows you to  use different namespaces in the other file.

Comment: That is good for a whole class, but I am not sure how to do it for a block of code, which might be a question.

Comment: While technically possible, `using aliases` are pretty smelly.  Now the code maintainer has to remember two names for something.  And when they go to use that enum in another code file that does not have the same alias they will get errors.  It's far better to use the fully qualified name.

Comment: This is the only option C# offers.

Comment: I was afraid this would be a limitation within the language.  Most languages allow adding ASomeEnum before the block and then just do .A, .B, .C, etc.